# This getline test works in MSVC 2012 but is an error in MSVC 2015, how can it be fixed?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
while (getline(stream, thisword, ' ') != 0) {...
```

I can compile this line under MSVC 2012. By passing a 'SPC' char as the string delimiter, it is supposed to test to see if there are any strings left in the input stream to process. It roughly checks to see if the pointer is NULL.

However, it doesn't work in MSVC 2015 and it won't compile. It is now a compilation error, not a warning.

How do I update the fragment so it checks to see if the end of the input stream was reached?

Comment: If you get a compilation error, you should put that error message here (verbatim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getline` returns a reference to the `basic_istream` object that it was called with. Back in the olden days, `basic_istream` had a conversion operator that returned `void*`, and you could compare that with `0`. Now it has an `explicit operator bool()`, so you should remove the `!= 0` (which wasn't really needed in the first place).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! It Works! :-) It's an improvement over the old one too. :-)